# Spurious ^G (BELL) characters in JUnit log making CruiseControl barf

Tags: xml, ant, junit, cruisecontrol

I have a CruiseControl build server running a large number of projects. On one of them I have recently noticed that only one of the two test suites are present in the build report (but failures in the other one still cause the build to fail).

Further investigation showed that the XML output file of JUnit generated by ant's xmlformatter (which CruiseControl parses to produce build reports) contains **occasional instances of the ASCII code 7 (BELL) character**, inside a CDATA section containing the system-out of a test case. Cruiscontrol apparently cannot deal with this and xmllint also considers these characts illegal within a CDATA section.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything that would write these characters; they appear at the beginning of a particular line of log output, but not always (though the logging code always prints the same string literal).

And shouldn't the xmlformatter produce valid XML no matter what a test case writes to its standard output?

Has anyone had similar problems?

This is how the relevant sections of the XML logfile looks like (anonymized since this is a corporate app):

```
  <testcase classname="Testclass" name="testMethod" time="0.0020"></testcase>
  <system-out><![CDATA[15.10.09 16:49:41.161 (MainUIClass): Starte UI initialize
...
^G15.10.09 16:49:58.881 (SubUiClass): Starte UI initialize
15.10.09 16:49:58.881 (SubUiClass): UI initialize beendet
^G15.10.09 16:49:59.264 (SubUiClass): Starte UI initialize
15.10.09 16:49:59.264 (SubUiClass): UI initialize beendet
```

This is the code producing that log output:

```
SystemProperties.getLogger().logInfo(getClass(), "Starte UI initialize");
...
SystemProperties.getLogger().logInfo(getClass(), "UI initialize beendet");
```

Comment: Very interesting problem! Could you please post some of the infected XML? I think it would be helpfull, thanks!

Comment: Does it always occur on "Starte UI initialize"? Or better: Does it always occur _after_ "UI initialize beendet"? Btw, greetings from Germany ;)

Comment: Could you please change the encoding of the Java file? May be there invisible characters. Have you tried rewriting the log lines?

Comment: It seems to be always between those two lines (but not everytime they occur). However, those occur much more often than anything else in the sysout stream. In some cases there are multiple BELL characters at the beginning of a line. And I've checked the source files - nothing fishy in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found out that the problematic characters are part of the tests's stdout stream and are produced by the `beep()` method of `sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit`, i.e. the `Toolkit` implementation that is used when, as is the case on the build server, the `java.awt.headless` system property set to `true`.

It seems clear to me that this is first and foremost a bug in ant's xmlformatter for JUnit logs, which (I'd say) should produce valid XML output no matter what is in the stdout stream.

**Edit** I was using an old version of ant; the current version (1.7.1) does not have this problem.

Comment: That's definitely a WTF... Show me the bug entry and I'll vote for it.